# Is client side spring-ws connection pooling possible?

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client, spring-ws

We are making below SOAP call from `spring-ws`

```
<bean id="OrderSubmitWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="serviceMarshaller"></property>
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="serviceMarshaller"></property>
        <property name="defaultUri" value="${eoe.SubmitOrderWebService.url}" />
        <property name="messageSender">
            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
                <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${eoe.SubmitOrderWebService.connectionTimeout}" />
                <property name="readTimeout" value="${eoe.SubmitOrderWebService.readTimeout}" />
            </bean>
        </property>     
    </bean>
```

**The Comment from the WebService-Hosting was :**
You are grouping many separate requests into a single HTTP connection in a single TCP connection. They also said we are sending a load balancer cookie that concentrates traffic on one web server (which could be a result of a few things, but it’s likely because you are keeping these connections for a very long time). The overall effect is reducing our ability to balance load.

**WS-Host's recommendation was :** either send only one WS request per TCP connection OR regularly break the connection.  They suggest there is likely a “Keep-Alive timeout” or a “maximum requests per connection” setting somewhere.

I tried adding below 2 lines, but I dont believe that's solution to the problem - since the ***eoe.SubmitOrderWebService.url*** should be their load-balancer URL.

```
<property name="maxConnectionsPerHost"><map><entry key="${eoe.SubmitOrderWebService.url}" value="20" /></map></property>
<property name="maxTotalConnections" value="100"/>
```

We are using
**Tomcat** -6.0.39 , **JDK** - 1.6, **spring-ws-core** : 2.1.2.RELEASE

**Update on Jan,21/2015** : I was using older version of spring-ws 2.1.2.Release and hence it had below - have changed it to 2.1.4.RELEASE... thank you @ArtemBilan

Based on above 
`PoolingConnectionManager` maintains a maximum limit of connection on a per route basis and in total. Per default this implementation will create no more than than 2 concurrent connections per given route and no more 20 connections in total.

**Update on Apr,1/2015** : We are notified that above change didnot make any significant improvement.

Our 4 servers submits request approx 25% each server to their load balancer but their server processing is 11k on First server, 4k on 2nd server and rest few 100s processed by other 3 servers, Diagrammatic representation as below:

```
                                                  ____ Server 1 - processed 11,000 requests
Our server 1 (sent 4k)---\       |Their WS|      /___ Their Server 2 - processed 4,000 
Our server 2 (sent 4k)--- \______|Load    |_____/____ Server 3 - processed 100 requests
Our server 3 (sent 4k)----/      |Balancer|     \____ Server 4 - processed 400 requests
Our server 4 (sent 4k)---/       |URL     |      \___ Server 5 - processed 500 requests
```

WS-Host's current comments are as below:

- Our application is not closing TCP connections often enough.
- Our application (keep-alive?) connections are not allowing the IHS load balancer to release the connection started by the original request started by our application.

Any suggestions for improvement appreciated..

Answer (score 4):

If we take a look to the `HttpComponentsMessageSender` source code, will see that it is pooling by default:

```
  /**
     * Create a new instance of the {@code HttpClientMessageSender} with a default {@link HttpClient} that uses a
     * default {@link PoolingClientConnectionManager}.
     */
    public HttpComponentsMessageSender() {
        DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new PoolingClientConnectionManager());
        defaultClient.addRequestInterceptor(new RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor(), 0);
......
```

So, it is an robust answer to your question: it is not only possible, it is by default.

However we have that only when we use Commons HTTP. With the standard Java `HttpURLConnection` we don't have such an option.

Comment: I was using older version of spring-ws 2.1.2.Release and hence it had  below - have changed it to 2.1.4.RELEASE... thank you

<code>public HttpComponentsMessageSender() {
        DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager());

Comment: Sorry, do you need anything else here?

Comment: Yes please Artem, I have updated question with details after Apr timestamp

Comment: You can to use `httpMethod.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")` to prevent `keep-alive` and, please, find more info here: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html regarding performance improvement

Comment: Artem, I have not figured out how to set the property on spring webservice code snippet near top part of question, any clues appreciated..

Comment: You are forced to declare one more bean for the `HttpClient` and use from that `HttpComponentsMessageSender` definition.